# How can I speed up Ubuntu 16.04 as much as I can? Should I switch to GNOME from builtin Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, performance

I read that "gnome is more stable than unity" and I am wondering if it could help speed up my system.

I'm experiencing some performance problems, for example:

- Android Studio felt obviously slow, and even hung when 2 Android Studio windows were opened simultaneously.

  2. In Zealdoc searchbox, Sublime command pallete I can only input one character.

Any advice is appreciated, and below is the hardware profile.

CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
Memory: 8GB
HD: 500G 7200 RPM, 180G SSD (Win10 on it)

Comment: Not sure if Unity is your overhead, you might want to check your processes and resources being used with system monitor. If Unity is causing you the trouble then give a go to mate.

Comment: You can try (with separate live and/or dual boot installed systems alongside your current operating system) Ubuntu community flavours with lighter desktop environments, **Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, Xubuntu**. See this link: [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

Answer (score 1):

Just keep calm and run Ubuntu [MATE](http://mate-desktop.org/) with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

Then select MATE session on login screen.